# session.save_path incorrect in magento + memcache for session

Tags: magento, session, memcached, php

I am trying to configure Magento to use memcache for session. I have installed memcached and also php5-memcache. I have also added "extension=memcache.so" in memcache.ini.

I have made sure the memcached instance is also running in the localhost port number 11213. However, when I try to login to Magento admin I get an error -

```
Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (memcache). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (tcp://127.0.0.1:11213?persistent=0&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10)  in Unknown on line 0
```

The following is the memcache configuration in local.xml -

```
<session_save><![CDATA[memcache]]></session_save>
<session_save_path><![CDATA[tcp://127.0.0.1:11213?persistent=0&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10]]></session_save_path>
```

The following are the grep for memcached,

```
www-data    1329     1  0 08:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/memcached -d -m 64 -p 11213 -u www-data -l 127.0.0.1
www-data  1511     1  0 08:18 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/memcached -d -m 64 -p 11211 -u www-data -l 127.0.0.1
www-data  1518     1  0 08:18 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/memcached -d -m 64 -p 11212 -u www-data -l 127.0.0.1
```

I have been meddling up with this for a couple of days now and I am not sure what the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
G

Comment: Have you restarting  the Apache and memcache server.. i faced this problem it worked with restarting

Comment: @Chanz yes a lot of times :) did not help...Btw, it is nginx+php5-fpm not apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note there is a difference between `memcache` and `memcached`. I’ve found that the Magento sessions integration expects you to use this:

```xml
<session_save><![CDATA[memcached]]></session_save>
```

You should install the PHP memcached libraries, as well.